# SQL Server 2008 - Add to string in particular position within name column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have been asked to do a job which is beyond my SQL skills a little and having done some research online, cannot quite find the write solution to be done in SQL Server 2008 and not MySQL.

I have a table where I need to update specific names by adding an additional string after a certain point whilst keeping the rest of the string to the right intact.

```
e.g.

Current Name = 'Name - Location - 0005'
New Name = 'Name (West) - Location - 0005'
```

As you can see I need to add the text (West), I have a table which lists all the codes (e.g. 0005) and I need to link that into my where clause to only update the relevant names.

So the questions are:

1 - How can I update the Name by adding additional text at a set location (5th character), whilst maintaining whatever text is to the right of the names

2 - Is there a way that I can do a sort of like in to check the code, I tried using Contains however the table is not full-text indexed. This is not a massive issue as I can manually create update statement using just like for each row within the table, would just be a nice to know to add to my knowledge base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the help of `STUFF` we can achieve this

```
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )
SELECT STUFF('Name - Location - 0005', 5, 0, ' (West)');
```

output would be `Name (West) - Location - 0005`

Answer (score 0):

Use STUFF function

```
declare @names varchar(100)
set @names='Name - Location - 0005'
select stuff(@names,5,0,' (West)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string replacement to insert the `(West)` like so:

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(30) = 'Name - Location - 0005'

SELECT REPLACE(@val, 'Name ', 'Name (West) ')
```

Taking this a step further to perform an update with a `WHERE` clause to filter records ending with `'0005'`, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @val NVARCHAR(30) = 'Name - Location - 0005'

SELECT  @val AS Val
INTO    #temp

UPDATE  #temp
SET     Val = REPLACE(@val, 'Name ', 'Name (West) ')
WHERE   RIGHT(Val, 4) = '0005'

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

This assumes the format is consistent. You may need to tweak it if `Name` can appear more than once or if the `0005` can appear in positions other than the end of the value.